# sql loader - check for specific field value

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, sql-loader

I have a field called "FLOATVALUE" in csv/text file. I receive this file from third party, this has below possible values

> 1. NULL
> 2. {}
> 3. Any number

When I insert this value as below

> ....  [OTHER FIELD CHECKS]
>
> `isValid          "nvl(:isValid, '')",`
>
> ***`FLOATVALUE            FLOAT EXTERNAL "nvl(:FLOATVALUE, NULL)"`***
>
> .... [OTHER FIELD CHECKS]

Its checking whethre ":FLOATVALUES" is null or not. If yes it's inserting NULL into the oracle table, if not it's failing to insert for the values ("{}").

The field I'm loading into oracle table is 'FLOATVALUE FLOAT'. I would like to have something like below in my control file -

> 1. if :FLOATVALUE is null insert NULL
>    elseif :FLOATVALUE is '{}' insert NULL
>    else inert original value

How can specify a condition like above in control file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [decode](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions049.htm) function:

```
decode(:FLOATVALUE, '{}', NULL, :FLOATVALUE)
```

That says: if FLOATVALUE is '{}', insert NULL, otherwise insert FLOATVALUE

Answer (score 0):

You can use either decode  or case when statement. See the example below

```
Decode :
decode(Float_value,{},NULL,Float_value);

Case when :
CASE  [ FLOAT_VALUE ]
WHEN NULL THEN NULL
WHEN {} THEN NULL
ELSE [FLOAT_VALUE]
END;
```